# Find last data point in a pattern

Tags: r, time-series

Given the following data set and code, I can find the first data point in the pattern, but how can i find the last data point in the pattern?

```
d<-read.table(text='Date.Time Aerial
794  "2012-10-01 08:18:00"      1
795  "2012-10-01 08:34:00"      1
796  "2012-10-01 08:39:00"      1
797  "2012-10-01 08:42:00"      1
798  "2012-10-01 08:48:00"      1
799  "2012-10-01 08:54:00"      1
800  "2012-10-01 08:58:00"      1
801  "2012-10-01 09:04:00"      1
802  "2012-10-01 09:05:00"      1
803  "2012-10-01 09:11:00"      1
1576 "2012-10-01 09:17:00"      2
1577 "2012-10-01 09:18:00"      2
804  "2012-10-01 09:19:00"      1
805  "2012-10-01 09:20:00"      1
1580 "2012-10-01 09:21:00"      2
1581 "2012-10-01 09:23:00"      2
806  "2012-10-01 09:25:00"      1
807  "2012-10-01 09:32:00"      1
808  "2012-10-01 09:37:00"      1
809  "2012-10-01 09:43:00"      1', header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, row.names=1)
```

I am able to find a pattern and identify the first data point in that pattern:

```
require(zoo)
##Pattern
pat <- c(1,1,2,2)
##Find pattern    
count<- function(fish,pat){x <- rollapply(fish$Aerial, length(pat), FUN=function(x)     all(x == pat))

                       fish[which(x),]
}                   
##call function
count(d,pat)
```

This prints the first data point(s) where the pattern is found:

```
 count(d,pat)
          Date.Time Aerial
802 2012-10-01 09:05:00      1
804 2012-10-01 09:19:00      1
```

How can i print the last data point in the pattern?

The adapted function would print:

```
     Date.Time Aerial
802 2012-10-01 09:18:00      2
804 2012-10-01 09:23:00      2
```

for the given data.

I have tried tail() in various ways but to no avail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the line in the function to:

```
fish[which(x),]
```

to

```
fish[which(x) + length(pat) - 1,]
```

Comment: I had that before, however without the   -1,]     what is exactly that this part of the code does? Thanks again!

Comment: @Salmosalar: `which` gets a series of indices where the pattern starts. But if you add `length(pat)` (4 in this case), you're not getting the end of the pattern- you're going one past the end of the pattern (try counting four items past where the pattern starts!)